# Got 404 Not Found from nowhere (I guess)

Tags: magento2, 404-page

So I was working fine with my site and my admin panel, but today I wanted to access my frontend and I see this

[image]

And in the tab I see

[image]

I can't neither access the backend.

What can be happening?
Thank you!!

Comment: did you fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This happens when your static view files aren't redeployed after running an upgrade.
 Try this solution, run the following commands:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade  
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Then check if your frontend works.

> Side Note: Remember to always run `static-content:deploy` every time you run an `upgrade` command